# How do you implement NSPageController to navigate through a webView's history

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, api, view, webview

I have a webView-based app, but I want the user to be able to navigate it with swiping on the trackpad and magic mouse. Therefore, I am going to implement NSPageController.

I have looked at the documentation and the PictureSwiper app, however those aren't really meant for a webView. So, I would like to know how I can use an NSPageController  on a webView. I have a webView defined as `webView` and two actions, goBack: and goForward: that load the previous and next page respectively.

However, I am unaware of how I get NSPageController to work with a simple webView. There has a to be a way to do it, but I see no way. If someone could please explain what I am suppose to do, that would be great. Or if you are feeling especially generous, you can download my free browser source example. https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/basic-web-browser

That source shows how my own app is pretty much set up. If you would like to implement the NSPageController on that app and send me the source, I would really appreciate it. It's not much, but if you do that I'll add the swiping example to Infinite Open Syntax and put your name on it. You can choose the license.

This is Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch

***EDIT***

Okay, now I just need to make sure the app still works on Snow Leopard. Supposedly, I can test this by disconnecting the outlets. It works fine, minus the back and forward button. To do this, I believe I check for the class NSPageController. If it doesn't exist, then I just skip using the pageController.

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"NSPageController") != Nil)
    {
        [self.pageController navigateBack:sender];
    }
    {

         //Not 10.8
        [webView goBack];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for NSPageController](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPageController_Class/) and [its delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/WindowsViews/NSPageControllerDelegate_Protocol/), and read through [the introduction of NSPageController in the AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html#10_8PageController)?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. I get the idea, however making it work with a webView confuses me. Since a webView is it's own view, and there is only one of it. How does the PageController work in that circumstance?

Comment: For reference, the question that led to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748072/how-to-properly-use-swipewithevent-to-navigate-a-webview-obj-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The download link on the page you linked to doesn't work, so I'll keep my answer more general.

You don't need to keep multiple WebViews or manually generate snapshots if you're using `NSPageController`; it takes care of that for you. In your case, you want to use `NSPageController` in [History Mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPageController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012265-CH1-SW19). To do that, wire your `WebView` to `pageController.view`. You will need to implement three `NSPageControllerDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition:(NSPageController *)pageController;
- (void)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController didTransitionToObject:(id)object;
- (void)pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition:(NSPageController *)pageController;
```

Every time the WebView goes to a new page (not through a back/forward action), call [`navigateForwardToObject:(id)object`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPageController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012265-CH1-SW14) on the `pageController`. I would make `object` a custom object that stores user state for a navigated page (scroll positions, highlighted text, form contents, etc.) as well as the page's [`WebHistoryItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebHistoryItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/WebHistoryItem). The user state can be undefined initially, but should get set in `pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition:`. Here's an example:

```
- (void)pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition:(NSPageController *)pageController
{
  // Remember user state
  MyCustomObject *object = [self.pageController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:self.pageController.selectedIndex];
  object.userState = someUserState;
}
```

When that method returns, the `pageController` will hide its view (the WebView) and display snapshots of previous states of its view instead.

Once the swiping animation is complete, `pageController:didTransitionToObject:` will get called. Cool. What you should do in that method is grab the `WebHistoryItem` out of `object` and have the WebView go back to that item using the [`goToBackForwardItem:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903-BABFADDF) method. You should also hold onto the user state you stored in `object` (say, in an instance variable), because you'll need to restore it once `WebView` finishes loading.

Lastly, in `pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition:` you do anything you want done before redisplaying the WebView. I expect that would be nothing, since the user state isn't restored until the WebView finishes loading, so all you would need in its implementation would be `[pageController completeTransition]`.

One last detail is the back/forward buttons. You should implement them as you would normally, but also have them call `navigateBack:` or `navigateForward:` on the pageController.

That pretty much covers it. I haven't actually tried this specific example, so let me know if you run into any problems.

### Edit

Here's how I'd modify your source to get basic `NSPageController` functionality. Add an `NSPageController IBOutlet` property in your AppDelegate header file. In your `MainMenu.xib` file add the page controller, wire its view to your WebView, make your AppDelegate its delegate, and give it a referencing outlet to the property we just created in the AppDelegate. Also, make your AppDelegate your WebView's `frameLoadDelegate`. Inside `basicWebAppDelegate.m` add a private property:

```
@interface basicWebAppDelegate ()
@property (assign) id currentItem;
@end
```

Then add the following inside implementation:

```
#pragma mark - WebFrameLoadDelegate

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didCommitLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
  if (frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
    id object = [sender.backForwardList currentItem];
    BOOL isCurrentItem = self.currentItem && (object == self.currentItem) ? YES : NO;
    if (!isCurrentItem) {
      [self.pageController navigateForwardToObject:[sender.backForwardList currentItem]];
    }
  }
}


#pragma mark - NSPageControllerDelegate

- (void)pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition:(NSPageController *)pageController {
  self.currentItem = [self.webView.backForwardList currentItem];
  // Here is where you'll save any state for your pageController.arrangedObjects[pageController.selectedIndex] object
}

- (void)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController didTransitionToObject:(id)object {
  BOOL isCurrentItem = self.currentItem && (object == self.currentItem) ? YES : NO;
  if (!isCurrentItem) {
    self.currentItem = object;
    [self.webView goToBackForwardItem:object];
  }
}

- (void)pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition:(NSPageController *)pageController {
  self.currentItem = nil;
  [pageController completeTransition];
}
```

Finally, change your `goBack:` and `goForward:` actions to just call `[self.pageController navigateBack:sender]` and `[self.pageController navigateForward:sender]`, respectively.

Note that I didn't bother saving any user state here and instead used `WebHistoryItem`s directly as the objects. You might need to do differently.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. Ill go fix the links. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Okay. I fixed the link. If you still want to make an example that would be great. Everything I said still stands.

Comment: I'm confused with these lines: `@interface basicWebAppDelegate ()
@property (assign) id currentItem;
@end`

Comment: Where do I put that. Did you mean in the .m? Seems to me like it should go in the header.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thank you so much. Now, is is okay if I add this to Open Syntax? You get to choose the license.

Comment: Yep, in the .m. Glad I helped! Use it as you'd like. MIT License. Cheers!

Comment: .M. I put it into the .H? As for the license that is fine. Do you want your name to be Cbrauchli?

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference where you put it. Putting it inside the `.m` file is a common design pattern that hides it from other classes and makes it clearer that it's a private property. "Chris Brauchli" is fine—if you could include a link to this question that would be great!

Comment: Sure. I'll do that later. Thanks again.

Comment: @AceLegend: An `@interface` line with `()` at the end of it denotes a class extension, which belongs in the .m.

Comment: @PeterHosey, Okay, thanks. But I do have one question. Is pageController available on Snow Leopard? If not, what will happen when the user hits the back-arrow. Will there just not be an animation? If anyone has Snow-Leopard, I would love to have you try the SwipingBrowser I am about to add to Open Syntax.

Comment: @AceLegend: If you look at the documentation for NSPageController, you'll see when it was introduced. You can see for yourself what will happen without a page controller by simply not connecting the outlet.

Comment: @PeterHosey, So disconnecting the two outlets (view and delegate), will show me what will happen on Snow Leopard. In that case I have some problems. Back and Forward button are useless (Although I can remedy that), but it seems to pop up another window each time I click a link. Not sure why. I get this error:

Comment: *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didCommitLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> -[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "(null)" nib but no view was set.

Comment: @AceLegend: Sounds like it still has a delegate and that delegate is still trying to create a page controller or other VC. I'd break on the exception and investigate.

Comment: @PeterHosey, Okay. You were right. I still had the referencing outlet connected. So the issue is gone, minus the back and forward buttons. All I need to do there is throw in an if statement and check if the OS is 10.7 or lower. The manually run webView:goBack, etc... I just need to look up how.

Comment: See my edit. I believe that should work, although, it just occurred to me... I think I need to swap those statements. If the Class does equal nil, then that means it does not exist right? In that case, I should not see if it is not true that it is nil.

Comment: @Josiah I am trying hard to follow this, but am having ton'o problems. Got my swipe working for 10.7/10.8 without NSPageController. Got an NSPageController instantiated for Mountain Lion. The delegate 'pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition' gets called, but for some reason nothing happens afterwards. Its like the WebHistoryItem is not populating the page controller's arrangedobjects. Any help???

Comment: @Arvin, Perhaps take a look at this: https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/swiping-web-browser  Note that I have had some issues with the image not showing immediately, but the swiping should still work. Try downloading that source code and see if it helps.

Comment: @Josiah I did, but it crashes for me when I swipe. I got things kinda working last night by using the webview frame delegate - didChangeLocationWithPageForFrame but things are just not lining up properly. e.g. I click a link and then swipe backwards and the animation image does not show the previous page. Instead I see the current page. Can I contact you more directly and then I can share some code so we can collaborate?

Comment: @Arvin, Yeah sure. Email me at josiah@programmer.net Though I too have the problem of pages not showing immediately. (If I click on a link, and swipe back, the image does not appear properly. But I can swipe back and it would work. And then going to the page again will work.)

Comment: @Josiah I am gonna work on a book mode implementation and will let you know. From NSPageController doco "When using the book mode, if pageController.view is layer backed, live layers are used during transition instead of snapshots." If you pay close attention to how the Safari animation's are you will see the same thing where live layers are used versus snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716988/466698

An obvious solution might be to use multiple web views, but as they can be pretty heavy-weight, you probably don’t want to.

The best idea is probably to save an image of each page before navigating away from it. When the use swipes back, show a view with just the saved image. Once the swipe is complete, swap the views around so the web view itself is on top.

This appears to be how Safari does it (you can see the image compression sometimes, and it often reloads the page and it jumps around away from the previous screenshot)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But how would you go about doing that?