# How to remove object from NSPageController arrangedObjects?

Tags: objective-c, macos

How to add/remove objects in the page controller dynamically? All examples out there set the arrangedObjects property during the awakeFromNib method once during the application lifetime.

In my application I have NSMutableArray of NSObjects that I display in the main window using NSPageController. For each NSObject I create corresponding ViewController in the delegate's - `(NSViewController *) pageController:(NSPageController *) pageController
          viewControllerForIdentifier:(NSString *) identifier` method.

During program execution objects will get added/removed asynchronously to/from the mutable array.
At every event I set the page controller's arrangedObjects to the mutable array to account for the change - display new objects and stop showing removed ones.

When objects are added it all works fine. But when removing objects the associated views/view controllers remain in memory.

How can I "reset" the page controller so that it forgets everything about the removed objects?

Looks like the page controller keeps references (snapshots) of the view controllers of removed objects. And when adding another objects their views are messed up.

Comment: were you able to find any answer to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a NSPageController in History Mode as described here

[How do you implement NSPageController to navigate through a webView's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747190/how-do-you-implement-nspagecontroller-to-navigate-through-a-webviews-history)

and here

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPageController_Class/

In this case you do NOT need to implement

```
pageController:identifierForObject:
```

and

```
pageController:viewControllerForIdentifier
```

and no need to set

```
arrangedObjects
```

But you NEED to call

```
navigateForwardToObject
```

each time you want to open a new page, this method makes NSPageController clear forward history and open a new page.
Also make something like adding a new view to your pageController.view with a new page in this method.
Also I made view replacement in

```
didTransitionToObject
```