# Using NSPageController in History Mode (Content Mode) and no View Controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, navigation

I'm building an app with three views and I want the user to be able to swipe between them but also navigate between them by using custom buttons, like browsing in safari but only with three available views. The user can navigate between them in a somewhat random order and I provide back and forward buttons in a toolbar.

After reading Apple's documentation I believe history mode is the option I'm looking for as I can provide the views separately and navigation is not predefined like in book mode, however when I implement it it adds my view to the `arrangedObjects` property but the view itself doesn't change. I've correctly wired the page controller view programmatically to a subview of the app's `contentView` and I can see said view correctly displayed while debugging the view hierarchy.

[image: Storyboard View Hierarchy]
*The "Page Controller Managed View" is set as `NSPageController.view` programatically.*

When I try using `navigateForward(to:)` the view gets added correctly to the `arrangedObjects` and the `selectedIndex` is correctly set but the `NSPageController.view` doesn't change at all (remains a blank NSView like the loaded view from storyboard). This is my code:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {
    
    // MARK - Instance Properties
    var notificationObservers: Array<NSObjectProtocol> = []
    var pageController: NSPageController?
    
    // MARK - Interface Builder Outlets
    @IBOutlet var mainContentView: NSView?   // Named "Page Controller Managed View" in storyboard
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pageController = (NSStoryboard.main!.instantiateController(
            withIdentifier: "MainPageController") as! NSPageController)
        
        pageController!.delegate = AppDelegate
        pageController!.view = mainContentView!
        
        notificationObservers.append(
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                forName: NSApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification,
                object: NSApp,
                queue: .main,
                using: { [weak self] (notification) in
                    // If the 'arrangedObjects' property is 0 it means no other object has set the first view
                    if self?.pageController!.arrangedObjects.count == 0 {
                        // Set the first view
                        self.pageController!.navigateForward(to: AppDelegate.firstView.nsView)
                    }
            })
        )
    }
    
    deinit {
        // Perform cleanup of any Apple Notification Center notifications to which we may have registered
        notificationObservers.forEach { (observer) in
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    
}
```

*This is the view hierarchy while running the app:*
[image: View hierarchy while running the app]

What am I doing wrong? Why is the page controller view not being updated with the `navigateForward(to:)` view?

This could shorten the amount of code I have to use by a lot compared to using view controllers (Book mode) so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [How do you implement NSPageController to navigate through a webView's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747190/how-do-you-implement-nspagecontroller-to-navigate-through-a-webviews-history)

Comment: @Willeke Yes! I did look at that question, I didn't include the delegate in the post as they really do nothing except call `completeTransition()` in the `pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_)` but it's there, I'd say I did everything like that question suggests but the problem remains...