# Two finger swipe in Yosemite 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have been using a similar method to as this:

https://github.com/oscardelben/CocoaNavigationGestures

To capture two finger swipes on the Mac, under Yosemite it is no longer working. Anyone know what has change, or what I need to change for this to work.

Comment: Hi, this may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748072/how-to-properly-use-swipewithevent-to-navigate-a-webview-obj-c - It pretty much implies that the original two-finger swipe mechanism is not really supported and only worked if one of the preference settings was changed (which *may* be what Fusseldieb was trying to say in his answer).

Comment: I am actually working on a solution by dissecting how chrome handles it. I will post my solution when finished. https://github.com/darwin/chromium-src-chrome-browser/blob/master/renderer_host/chrome_render_widget_host_view_mac_history_swiper.mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution, seems to be working for me.

```
#define kSwipeMinimumLength 0.2
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event{
    if(event.type == NSEventTypeGesture){
        NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:self];
        if(touches.count == 2){
            self.twoFingersTouches = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            for (NSTouch *touch in touches) {
                [self.twoFingersTouches setObject:touch forKey:touch.identity];
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseEnded inView:self];
    if(touches.count > 0){
        NSMutableDictionary *beginTouches = [self.twoFingersTouches copy];
        self.twoFingersTouches = nil;

        NSMutableArray *magnitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSTouch *touch in touches)
        {
            NSTouch *beginTouch = [beginTouches objectForKey:touch.identity];

            if (!beginTouch) continue;

            float magnitude = touch.normalizedPosition.x - beginTouch.normalizedPosition.x;
            [magnitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:magnitude]];
        }

        float sum = 0;

        for (NSNumber *magnitude in magnitudes)
            sum += [magnitude floatValue];

        // See if absolute sum is long enough to be considered a complete gesture
        float absoluteSum = fabsf(sum);

        if (absoluteSum < kSwipeMinimumLength) return;

        // Handle the actual swipe
        // This might need to be > (i am using flipped coordinates), you can use an else to go forward also.
        if (sum > 0){
            NSLog(@"go back");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adapted your answer to swift 3: http://stylekit.org/blog/2017/01/26/two-finger-swipe/

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work well for me - it would often not detect the swipe. Instead, I overrode `wantsScrollEventsForSwipeTrackingOnAxis:(NSEventGestureAxis)axis` to return `YES` for the appropriate axis, then overrode `scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent` to detect scrolling. Works perfect every time.

Comment: This works for a single finger, how do you get two fingers to work with this?

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer in Swift 5.3, based on @bmuller would be:

```swift
    override func wantsScrollEventsForSwipeTracking(on axis: NSEvent.GestureAxis) -> Bool {
        return axis == .horizontal
    }
    
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        if event.scrollingDeltaX < 0 {
            print("Go forward")
        }
        else {
            print("Go back")
        }
    }
```

Multiple swipe events might be sent in a single gesture with this code. You may need to add phase(`NSEventPhase`) handling code to the `scrollWheel(...)` function e.g.

```swift
     override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

        guard event.phase == .began else {
            return
        }

        if event.scrollingDeltaX < 0 {
            print("Go forward")
        }
        else {
            print("Go back")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Mac, go to system preferences and you will find all the different settings of the trackpad.

From here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5710582

Hope I helped.

Comment: He's not asking how to set the user preference, he's talking about detecting it at run-time in a Cocoa application.

Comment: But as I know it is disabled by default in the system preferences.

Comment: It is not a problem with system preferences. The problem is that the code no longer works with an NSView.